# How do I set default collation for all tables that are created in a database?

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a database dump taken from a broken database that I need to import into a clean installation. However, the original database seem to have been set to use utf8_unicode_ci.

When importing this dump into clean database, all databases are created with the default utf8_general_ci which gives me duplicate entries for words including `ß`, because general makes `'ß' == 's'`, while as utf8_unicode_ci supposedly have `'ß' == 'ss'`.

But, when importing mysql always seems to select the default utf8_general_ci when creating the table, even though I set the database (schema) default to utf8_unicode_ci.

Is there any way to force it to create tables with utf8_unicode_ci without having to inject alter table statements in my dump? It is several GB in size and is gonna be a pain to modify manually.

Configuring MySQL system wide is fine.

I tried setting:

`collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci`

in my.cnf but that doesn't seem to set the default collation for table creation.

Comment: No, I'm importing using commandline, `mysql db_name < dbdump.sql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there is no way of forcing collation on newly created tables if you specify charset in your create statements, meaning that if you have:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
...
CHARSET=utf8;
```

It will implicitly set it to utf8_general_ci which is the default collation for that charset. This is regardless of database settings, system settings and connection settings.

I ended up invoking this:

```
 cat dump.sql|sed s/CHARSET=utf8/CHARSET=utf8\ COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci/ > dump_replaced.sql
```

and just waited.

Answer (score 12):

I was working on this same issue this morning and I was able to get the table collation set the following way.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `agtAgentTypes`;
CREATE TABLE `agtAgentTypes` (
  `agentTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `agentType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`agentTypeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For some reason it seems that engine and charset need an = but collation trips up if it has one. I tried it out because I noticed the [MySQL Charset Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-examples.html) were also not using the =.

This was tested against MySQL Community Server 5.5.32-cll-lve.

Comment: excellent, it worked for me as well. i had been trying with `=` and getting errors.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using phpmyadmin then read below article:

#### http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/138/Default+MySQL+character+set+and+collation#gs

OR try this way

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (column_list)
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]]

ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [COLLATE collation_name]
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-table.html)

Comment: But I dont want to change the create statements, all create statements are in the dump which is several GB large.

Comment: Look on the link I gave below. There's an instruction on how to use sed to update encoding in the dump.

Comment: well, it instructed on how to remove any charset specifications in the dump. I ended up replacing the CREATE statements using sed directly in the dump, because a charset specifications implicitly sets the collation, iwth no regard of collation on the DB or connection.